# Getting statistics of windows phone apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, statistics, windows-phone-8, marketplace

I am in charge of developing a windows phone app which should be able to show statistics from windowsphone dashboard

Is there any API where someone can get Statistics of windows phone Apps like total downloads, downloads per day,.. ect

or please suggest me how to achieve this

Comment: Are you just wanting stats on your own app? If so, there is an app that does it for you, Dev Center: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/dev-center/2d3063c2-4b29-4e69-9c03-50b67b0e6aec. I don't think you'll be able (and don't think you should be able) to get stats for others' apps.

Comment: @ihan16 thanks for your responce nad is it possible to get data in web application by parsing that dashboard page

Answer (score 1):

One alternative for retrieving data is to use `mimvi api` - [here is a link](http://www.mimvi.com/)

`mimvi` offers search: `http://api.mimvi.com/1.1/search?q={0}&platform=windows`
the response is `json` and you have basic information about rating,version,price etc.

i hope this can help you.

Comment: Tnaks for your replay :) and how can i get total downloads

Comment: I don't think it is possible to see how many times someone elses app was downloaded from the store.

Comment: suppose i have the login credentials of others is it possible by parsing the html??

Comment: sorry mate, i am not sure, i have never try that (:

Comment: yesterday i have found something interesting, an app called flurry, it seems to me that it's perfect for your case http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can access the download count and many other details about your app through the dashboard. You can also see reviews, ratings and telemetry data if you have opted for that in your app. There is no API to track downloads currently.

This is for both Windows Phone and Windows 8 store
[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsstore/thread/0420c55e-a246-4e4e-b4ae-825e990cfbb3)

Comment: Looks like someone found a way to do it, so there must be a way http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/marketplace-dashboard/2552b582-2b8e-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8

Comment: it looks like that app has an internal web browser and a lot of HTML parse work :D

Comment: You are correct! I installed after writing this and hadn't had time to update that very thing. I already deleted it. It's too bad. Nice concept, but web scrapping is a bad way to go these days. This isn't the best in the world, but it's from Microsoft and gives you the basics on your phone. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/dev-center/2d3063c2-4b29-4e69-9c03-50b67b0e6aec